# Why does Array.prototype.filter remove empty elements regardless of the callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with some empty elements in it and I am calling `.filter` on that array with a callback that always returns true.

```
[1, 2, , 5].filter(() => true);
```

The result of the above code is `[1, 2, 5]` - the empty element is no longer there. This isn't what I'd expect, because the callback returns true.

For comparison, `Array.prototype.map` **does** execute the callback for empty items:

```
[1, 2, , 5].map(x => x); // returns [1, 2, , 5]
```

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): "`callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values"

Comment: ^^ but is says for map as well.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map does execute the callback for empty items:` it does not in Chrome:  `[1, 2, , 5].map((item) => console.log('item:',item) || true);` So even though your map function isn't called the enpty item does show up in the result.

Comment: @HereticMonkey [the docs for `.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) also say the same thing, but clearly that isn't the case

Comment: In `map`, the callback is not called for each element (as HMR's logging callback will show), but keys are preserved, leaving the empty slots in the result. Filter does not preserve keys (as filtering often shifts keys around), so those are lost.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `map`, the callback is not called for each element (as you can see by logging the value inside the callback to `map`), but keys are preserved, leaving the empty slots in the result. Filter does not preserve keys (as filtering often shifts keys around), so those are lost. Neither operation actually runs the callback on empty slots, though.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns `undefined` for sparse items instead of calling the callback, but keeps the same length of the array.

> **22.1.3.16 Array.prototype.map ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )**
>
> *`callbackfn`* is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for
>   missing elements of the array.

```js
console.log([1, 2, , 5].map((v, i) => [i, v]));
```

Comment: This is even true for filter https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter